# Simple JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not assigning properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This should work and it's very basic. My json string is (from the debugger):

```
json    "{\"companyId\":0,\"companyName\":\"Windward 3\",\"apiKey\":null,\"isEnabled\":false,\"isActive\":false,\"accruedRtusThisMonth\":0,\"billedRtusThisMonth\":0,\"overageChargesThisMonth\":0.0,\"pricingMode\":3,\"discount\":null,\"billingMode\":1,\"maxAdditionalMonthlyCharge\":123.0,\"billing\":{\"personId\":0,\"companyId\":0,\"isActive\":false,\"isAdmin\":false,\"isBilling\":false,\"firstName\":\"David\",\"lastName\":\"Thielen\",\"address1\":\"1 Main St.\",\"address2\":null,\"city\":\"Boulder\",\"state\":\"CO\",\"country\":\"USA\",\"postalCode\":\"80301\",\"phone\":\"123-456-7890\",\"email\":\"david@windward.net\",\"password\":\"tree\"},\"creditCard\":{\"cardNumber\":\"4111111111111111\",\"expiration\":\"2015-02-18T23:37:01.3135786Z\",\"cvv\":\"123\",\"useCardPerson\":false,\"cardPerson\":null},\"nextBaseBillingDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"nextOverageBillingDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"billingStatus\":0,\"billingErrorDate\":null,\"deactivateDate\":null,\"deleteDate\":null}"   string
```

My code is as follows:

```
CompanyWrapper companyWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyWrapper>(json,
                                                new JsonSerializerSettings());
```

And the CompanyWrapper class is:

```
public class CompanyWrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For the JSON population.
    /// </summary>
    public CompanyWrapper()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For unit tests
    /// </summary>
    public CompanyWrapper(string companyName, PricingPlan.PRICING_MODE pricingMode, Company.BILLING_MODE billingMode, decimal maxAdditionalMonthlyCharge, PersonWrapper billing, CreditCardWrapper creditCard)
    {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.pricingMode = pricingMode;
        this.billingMode = billingMode;
        this.maxAdditionalMonthlyCharge = maxAdditionalMonthlyCharge;
        this.billing = billing;
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The primary key. This is auto-generated in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public int companyId { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The company name. This cannot be changed.
    /// </summary>
    public string companyName { get; private set; }
...
}
```

On return companyWrapper.companyName == null. That should be assigned. What am I missing?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the property setters public.

Comment: Aargh - json.NET won't use reflection to set private ones? Dapper does that and it's really nice because we can retain the private for all our code. Anyways, that was it - all works now. Thanks.